TPL Dataflow WPF - Block is getting hosed up while await for Task to complete - .NET Framework 4.8
I am writing a File Transfer Pipeline using TPL library. I am new to this types of implementation so my issue could be related to something I am not aware of. Part of my application allows users to upload projects (bundles of files) to the cloud and I am trying to do these tasks in parallel and in chucks.
Here is what the current dataflow pipeline looks like:

As you can see from the flow above file are added to Incoming Files, if file needs to be compressed, then the file is compressed in the compress block and then uploaded to the cloud in the upload files block.
At this point everything seem s to be working fine as long as I dont set the 'BoundedCapacity' property of the IncomingFiles block.
When I set the BoundedCapacity property for the IncomingFiles block, the code seems to run until that capacity is hit and stops there.
Projects can have in average 500k files and I do not want those to be buffered at one time, which is why I am trying to set the BoundedCapacity.
Here is the code for my transfer pipeline, if you need more input or context, I would be happy to provide more:
    var incomingFiles = new TransformBlock<IUploadFile, IUploadFile>(file => file, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{ 
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50, BoundedCapacity = 5
});
var compressFiles = new TransformBlock<IUploadFile, IUploadFile>(TryCompressFiles, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50,
    BoundedCapacity = 5
});
   
var uploadFiles = new TransformBlock<IUploadFile, IUploadFile>(f =>
{
    _project.Server.UploadFile(f, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    return f;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{BoundedCapacity = 5, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50});

   
var errorHandler = new ActionBlock<IUploadFile>(file =>
{
    Debug.Write("Error\n");
},new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), CancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token
});


var count = 0;
var updateProgress = new ActionBlock<IUploadFile>(uf =>
{
    count++;
    Debug.Write(count+"\n");
},new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), CancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token
});

var dataflowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion = false};
incomingFiles.LinkTo(compressFiles, dataflowLinkOptions, file => file is ICompressibleFile);
incomingFiles.LinkTo(uploadFiles, dataflowLinkOptions);
   
compressFiles.LinkTo(uploadFiles, file => file != null);
compressFiles.LinkTo(errorHandler);
   
uploadFiles.LinkTo(updateProgress);

var filesToUpload = _project.GetFilesToUpload();
foreach (var uploadFile in filesToUpload)
    incomingFiles.Post(uploadFile);

incomingFiles.Complete();

await incomingFiles.Completion.ContinueWith(t => compressFiles.Complete());
await compressFiles.Completion.ContinueWith(t => uploadFiles.Complete());

await uploadFiles.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    errorHandler.Complete();
    updateProgress.Complete();
});

And again, if changed the definition of Incoming Files to the following, it works fine:
var incomingFiles = new TransformBlock<IUploadFile, IUploadFile>(file => file, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{ 
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
});



You may want to replace the incomingFiles.Post(uploadFile); with await incomingFiles.SendAsync(uploadFile);. You could try it and tells us if it solves the problem.

BTW Seems to me you did not get the idea of the dataflow (setting Parallelism for every block to 50). Compressing file is a heavy task for the local cpu and you allow up to 50 in parallel which make only sens if you have more than 50 cores

Also don't use continuations. Tell the blocks to propagate completion.

Then, if you don't want to have all the files' contents in memory at once (which probably would be impossible anyway), don't queue the content, but the paths and let the pipeline read the content as needed. Backpressure then should hold the memory consumption at bay.

@Fildor How would you set the propagation for the example above? The suggestion from Theodor worked but I am curious on how to set up propagations, I am running into issues where compressFiles block is waiting for all items to be finished before sending them to UploadFiles, where I want as soon as 1 file is finished compressed I want it to be sent to the upload Files block (upload files cant happen before file is compressed if it needs it). Thanks

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.propagatecompletion?view=net-8.0 but I'd also have a look here https://github.com/theodorzoulias/SimpleTplDataflowPipelines

@Fildor is there an option for specifying a predicate using that library, I cant seem to find it.

I don't know. The point was actually the explanation why it exists. DataFlow has some ... quirks, you know.

@Fildor to be honest I wouldn't recommend to anyone to use my library. If you need a library to fix a library, you might not want to use either of those libraries. Nowadays I recommend against using the TPL Dataflow for business applications in general. It's not a robust tool (it behaves poorly in case of exceptions), so I would use it only for experimental or one-off stuff where robustness is not a requirement.

As I said, I was going for the explanation why it exists, actually. I saw the bounded blocks and googled and your readme seemed a good explanation. @TheodorZoulias -- that said: your recommendation would be to do a custom implementation? Or something else?

@Fildor yep, I would go with the Parallel.ForEachAsync. Not a pipeline but simple and robust. In general the performance benefits of using a pipeline are not impressive. I would use a pipeline if an excellent tool existed in .NET for this purpose (either built-in or 3rd party), but I don't know of one.

Hmm, if OP did that and started with file paths, not content, they maybe could even stream data "directly" from disc instead of reading whole files into memory... just an idea.

@Fildor the file naming convention might be a little confusing, but I am working with file paths not the actual file loaded to memory.
